# Tableau. publish one single percentage from a table in a dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table which measure % of distribution of two distinct values in a dataset (I had a count, replaced with Percentage ) . I want to publish only the 85% value in a dashboard . which are the steps to do that ? .
Now, if i filter out the NO values, the YES will become 100% .

```
VALUE   SCORE
YES     85%
NO      15%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sheet you can right click the 'NO' value and hit the Hide Option which would hide only the 'NO' level and retain the 'Yes' with 85%.

[image]